# Angular how to have multiple selected

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, multi-select

I have this array of objects. that holds somethings like this.

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Extra Cheese"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "No Cheese"
    }
]
```

im iterating thru the array here

```
<select ng-model="item.modifiers" multiple chosen class="chosen-select" tabindex="4" ng-options="modifier._id as modifier.name for modifier in modifiers"></select>
```

The thing item.modifiers model that has an array of this 2 id

```
[
    1,2
]
```

I want the multi select to auto selected the two ids that are in the item.model

I want the final result to look something like this

[image]

Comment: Is there an external library that we should know about ? The multi-select screenshot, is that already done on the front end and you only want to know how to set the selected options initially ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is pretty much working already, maybe some of the variables are not assigned correctly (eg. `id` instead of `_id`)

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('Test', Test);

function Test($scope) {
  $scope.modifiers = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Extra Cheese"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "No Cheese"
    }
  ]
  
  $scope.item = {};
  
  // add this for pre-selecting both options
  $scope.item.modifiers = [1,2];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test'>
  <select ng-model="item.modifiers" multiple chosen class="chosen-select" tabindex="4" ng-options="modifier.id as modifier.name for modifier in modifiers"></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you're wanting to pre-select the two options.

To do this you will need to set your ng-model to point to the actual objects you are iterating over.

You will also need to change your ng-options to `ng-options="modifier as modifier.name for modifier in modifiers"` rather than just iterating over the ids.

Here's the relevant documentation under **Complex Models (objects or collections)**
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Something like this should work:

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="$ctrl.item.modifiers"
  ng-options="modifier as modifier.name for modifier in $ctrl.modifiers"
  multiple chosen class="chosen-select" tabindex="4" >
</select>
```

JS:

```
app.controller("my-controller", function() {
    var $ctrl = this;

    $ctrl.modifiers = [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Extra Cheese"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "No Cheese"
    }];

    $ctrl.item = {
      modifiers: []
    }

  $ctrl.$onInit = function() {
    const id1 = 1;
    const id2 = 2;
    for (const modifier of $ctrl.modifiers) {
      if (modifier.id === id1 || modifier.id === id2) {
        $ctrl.item.modifiers.push(modifier);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a pen showing the result:
http://codepen.io/Lahikainen/pen/WooaEx

I hope this helps...

Comment: Obviously, I don't know how you're pre-populating your model so that part in that populates it can probably be improved :)